# How to run shell script which is stored in a String variable using Java?

Tags: java, bash, shell, runtime, processbuilder

I need to execute a shell script in Java. My shell script is not in a file, it is actually stored in a String variable. I am getting my shell script details from some other application.

I know how to execute different commands in Java as shown below:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    //Build command 
    List<String> commands = new ArrayList<String>();
    commands.add("/bin/cat");
    //Add arguments
    commands.add("/home/david/pk.txt");
    System.out.println(commands);

    //Run macro on target
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
    pb.directory(new File("/home/david"));
    pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
    Process process = pb.start();

    //Read output
    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
    String line = null, previous = null;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        if (!line.equals(previous)) {
            previous = line;
            out.append(line).append('\n');
            System.out.println(line);
        }

    //Check result
    if (process.waitFor() == 0) {
        System.out.println("Success!");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    //Abnormal termination: Log command parameters and output and throw ExecutionException
    System.err.println(commands);
    System.err.println(out.toString());
    System.exit(1);
}
```

In my case, I will have script information in a json string variable from which I am extracting the content of script:

```
{"script":"#!/bin/bash\n\necho \"Hello World\"\n"}
```

Below is my code in which I am extracting script content from above json and now I am not sure how can I execute this script and also pass some parameters to it. For now, I can pass any simple string parameters:

```
String script = extractScriptValue(path, "script"); // this will give back actual shell script

// now how can I execute this shell script using the same above program?
// Also how I can pass some parameters as well to any shell script?
```

After executing the above script, it should print out Hello World.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start a `Process` with the shell, and then send your script to its input stream. The following is just a proof of concept, you'll need to change some things (like creating the process with `ProcessBuilder`):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    // this is your script in a string
    String script = "#!/bin/bash\n\necho \"Hello World\"\n echo $val";

    List<String> commandList = new ArrayList<>();
    commandList.add("/bin/bash");

    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(commandList);
    builder.environment().put("val", "42");
    builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
    Process shell = builder.start();

    // Send your script to the input of the shell, something
    // like doing cat script.sh | bash in the terminal
    try(OutputStream commands = shell.getOutputStream()) {
        commands.write(script.getBytes());
    }

    // read the outcome
    try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(shell.getInputStream()))) {
        String line;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }

    // check the exit code
    int exitCode = shell.waitFor();
    System.out.println("EXIT CODE: " + exitCode);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Can you show me an example how can I use `ProcessBuilder` here? I have never used these API's so having confusion. I just added a ProcessBuilder in your suggestion and somehow it doesn't work for me. I don't see `Hello World` output getting printed out.

Comment: Edited to use a ProcessBuilder instead

Comment: BTW, just double checking that you are printing the shell output explicitly (using the process' `OutputStream`) and you are not expecting that the output will be printed out without doing nothing

Comment: Thanks for your edit. I didn't understand your last comment?

Comment: A process object has an input stream (you are going to write your script here) and an output stream (where the shell is going to write its output, like "hello world") You need to read this output stream and then printing it to your console. Just copy/paste/execute the code I wrote, you'll understand better.

Comment: Yes now I understood clearly what do you mean by that comment. Appreciated your help. One last thing, let's say if I want to pass a String or Integer variable value from java program to same shell script and then print out that value in shell script. How can we do that? Is this possible to do?

Comment: You can modify your script in your string to concatenate values, try `int myVar = 42; script = script + "\necho 'myVar = " + myVar + "';\n";`

Comment: hey are you around? have small question.

Comment: @user1950349 I'm here now, use the email I gave you last time, so we don't pollute this post with unnecessary messages (use Google hangouts)

Comment: Sure somehow I lost track of that as it was in the chat window and I closed it. Aah just found the chat room again. Let's talk [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89215/discussion-between-user1950349-and-morgano)